# how to use canonical to prevent duplicate content issue in php

Tags: php, osclass

I have changed url scheme in my website, now I am having duplicate content issue.
Anybody tell me how to solve it?

Old url scheme

```
http://domainname.com/index.php?page=item&id=14
```

New url scheme

```
http://domainname.com/category-name/subcategory-name/battery_i14
```

above both urls point to same content.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by 'duplicate content issue'?

Comment: I have some content on my webpages, I changed url scheme from normal to seo friendly permalinks, now in HTML Improvements in Google Webmaster tools marked pair of many pages that have Duplicate title tags and Duplicate meta descriptions.

Comment: Do this help in this situation <link rel="canonical" href="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" />

Answer (score 0):

You should use a 301 Permanently Moved header to redirect http://domainname.com/index.php?page=item&id=14 to http://domainname.com/category-name/subcategory-name/battery_i14

This way Google will replace the old URL for the new URL.

**Edit 1:**
You could use something like this in PHP:

```html
if ( strpos ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?page=item' ) !== false )
{
    // Construct new URL
    header ( 'HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently' );
    header ( 'Location: /category-name/subcategory-name/battery_i14' );
    exit;
}
```

This is just an example. Use REQUEST_URI to see which URL is requested. When Htaccess redirects the URL to /index.php?page=item&id=.. and you check $_GET['page'] you'll get an endless loop.

Comment: thanks, can you tell me easiest way to implement this in php.